# Watson Question and Answerとはどのようなサービスですか？

Tags: api, bluemix

Watson Question and Answerとはどのようなサービスですか？

Answer (score 4):

IBMのコグニティブコンピューティングシステムであるWatsonを使ったサービスであり、特定の知識分野に関する自然言語での問い合わせに対して、適切な回答を返すサービスです。

現時点では、Travel, Healthcareの2分野の知識ベース（コーパス）を活用することができ、自然言語での質門の意味を認識した上で、回答を返します。APIを通して質門を送信し、回答を受け取る事ができます。

結果には、回答候補文や信用度スコア、回答の根拠となった情報ソースへのリンク等が含まれます。

現時点では、英語のみに対応しており、また前述のようにTravel, Healthcareの2種類のみに対応しています。

使い方や使用方法のサンプルに関しては、下記を参考にして下さい。

[Getting started with the Question and Answer service](http://www.ibm.com/smarterplanet/us/en/ibmwatson/developercloud/doc/qaapi/)
[What's up, Watson? Using Watson QAAPI with Bluemix and NodeExpress](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/cloud/library/cl-watson-qaapi-app/)